# powershell copy data from csv to postgres

Tags: postgresql, powershell

hitting an issue where you hopefully can help me with:
I want to import a csv file to postgres with powershell. For this have written following code:

```
$ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$SQLServer;Port=$SLQPort;Database=$SQLDB;Uid=$SQLUser;Pwd=$SQLPass;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.ODBC.ODBCConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

$connection.Open()

$query= "copy sensorhistory from 'C:\Powershell_Scripts\Postgres\Eurogate\data\export.csv' Delimiter ',' csv header;"

$DBCmd = $connection.CreateCommand();
$DBCmd.CommandText   = $query
$DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$DBCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But I am getting the error "No such file or directory"
the link is correct and already made changes to allow access to everybody, but still not working.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Did you copy the CSV file to `\\$SQLServer\C$\Powershell_Scripts\Postgres\Eurogate\data\export.csv` first?

Comment: I am using a Windows machine for PostgresSQL which is in the same network. and try to read from the local machine and store the Data on the postgres Server

Comment: Right, but how would the DB engine access the local file system on the client machine? You either need to specify an accessible network path in the query (eg `... from '\\cyberoner1sLaptop\c$\...\export.csv' ...`), or copy the CSV file to the machine that hosts Postgres before executing the query.

Comment: You are absolutly right..... thanks a lot, this helped. I changed the path to a network path and now access is working.

Comment: That's great, you're welcome! I've posted a proper answer below, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're pointing to the wrong file system!

From the `$SQLServer` argument in the connection string, it appears that Postgres might be hosted on a remote machine.

When encountering a file path like `C:\[...]\export.csv` in a query, the database engine is going to ask the operating system to open the corresponding file, and the operating system goes "C:\? That's a local drive, let me find that file for you" - and fails to locate the file because you actually meant the `C:\` drive on *your computer*.

Two ways to fix this:

#### 1. Pass a network path in the query:

Update the query so the file path explicitly points to a file share on a different machine:

```
$query = "copy sensorhistory from '\\ClientComputer01\ShareName\path\to\data\export.csv' Delimiter ',' csv header;"
```

#### 2. Copy the file to the server that hosts Postgres

Of course, opening the file from the local filesystem wouldn't fail *if the file also existed there*. Assuming WinRM is configured in the environment and you have admin access on the DB server, copy the file ahead of time:

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SQLServer
Copy-Item C:\Powershell_Scripts\Postgres\Eurogate\data\export.csv -Destination C:\Powershell_Scripts\Postgres\Eurogate\data\ -ToSession $remoteSession
```

Alternatively, copy the file over SMB if you have write access to a file share:

```
Copy-Item C:\Powershell_Scripts\Postgres\Eurogate\data\export.csv \\$SQLServer\ShareName\path\to\data\
```

After which the DB engine will be able to open the new local copy of the file and you can keep the local file path in the query.